# How can I toggle an animation class on a specific dynamically-created element containing another class with pointer events?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to accomplish is using the pointer events on the carousel to add and remove the slide "dot" animation.

My goal is so that if the user mouses over the carousel, it pauses the autoplay and resets the interval which is in place, but I'd also like it to remove the animation class as well and then add that class back in when the user mouses out or goes to the next slide using either the manual selection option or the forward and backward arrows.

I've looked around and found plenty of answers using jquery but I don't want to use jquery at all and definitely not to solve one problem in an otherwise all JS project.

The closest I've gotten so far is below, but it only works on the first dot obviously because of the querySelector. My idea would be to somehow add an id to the `is-active` slide, target that id in the script, and then add and remove the class based on whether or not the current id's classList contains the animation and the `is-active` classes.

I tried doing that a variety of ways but I ended up assigning the id to every slide dot probably because they're being generated in javascript and added to the DOM as opposed to being individual elements already present.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

```js
// ----- slideshow declarations ----- //
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
// -------------------- //


// ----- mod function ----- //
const mod = (n, m) => (n % m + m) % m;
// -------------------- //


// ----- build slider ----- //
const slideShow = (elSlideShow) => {

  const slideAnim = 500;
  const pause = 7000;

  const elSlider = el('.slidesContainer', elSlideShow);
  const elsSlides = els('.slideCard', elSlider);
  const elsDots = [];

  let autoPlayInterval;
  let index = elsSlides.length;
  let currentSlide = 0;

  if (index < 2) return;
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- transition ----- // 
  const trans = (ms = slideAnim) => {
    const cMod = mod(currentSlide, index);

    elSlider.style.transitionDuration = `${ms}ms`;
    elSlider.style.transitionTimingFunction = "ease-in-out";
    elSlider.style.transform = `translateX(${(-currentSlide - 1) * 100}%)`;

    elsSlides.forEach((elSlide, i) => elSlide.classList.toggle('is-active', cMod === i));
    elsDots.forEach((elDot, i) => elDot.classList.toggle('is-active', cMod === i));
    elsDots.forEach((elDot, i) => elDot.classList.toggle('sliderDotHorizontalAnim', cMod === i));
  };
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- nav buttons ----- //
  const moveLeft = () => {
    if (currentSlide <= -1) return;
    currentSlide -= 1;
    trans();
  };

  const moveRight = () => {
    if (currentSlide >= index) return;
    currentSlide += 1;
    trans();
  };

  const goTo = (index) => {
    currentSlide = index;
    trans();
  };
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- create controls ----- // 
  const elPrev = elNew('a', {
    type: 'a',
    className: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
    onclick: () => moveLeft(),
  });

  const elNext = elNew('a', {
    type: 'a',
    className: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
    onclick: () => moveRight(),
  });

  const elNav = elNew('div', {
    className: 'slideNumberDots',
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    const elDot = elNew('a', {
      type: 'a',
      className: 'slideDot',
      onclick: () => goTo(i)
    });
    elsDots.push(elDot);
  }
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- slide autoplay ----- //
  const dotPlaying = () => {
    document.querySelector(".slideDot").classList.toggle('sliderDotHorizontalAnim', true);
  };

  const dotStopped = () => {
    document.querySelector(".slideDot").classList.toggle('sliderDotHorizontalAnim', false);
  };

  const autoplay = () => {
    autoPlayInterval = setInterval(moveRight, pause + slideAnim);
    dotPlaying();
  };

  const stop = () => {
    clearInterval(autoPlayInterval);
    dotStopped();
  };
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- handle clones ----- // 
  elSlider.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    if (currentSlide <= -1) currentSlide = index - 1;
    if (currentSlide >= index) currentSlide = 0;
    trans(0);
  });
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- handle pointer events ----- // 
  elSlideShow.addEventListener('pointerenter', () => stop());
  elSlideShow.addEventListener('pointerleave', () => autoplay());
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- insert controls ----- // 
  elNav.append(...elsDots);
  elSlideShow.append(elNav, elPrev, elNext);
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- slide clones ----- // 
  elSlider.prepend(elsSlides[index - 1].cloneNode(true));
  elSlider.append(elsSlides[0].cloneNode(true));
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- functions on load ----- // 
  trans();
  autoplay();
  // -------------------- //
};


// ----- initiate slideshow ----- // 
els('.slideShow').forEach(slideShow);
// -------------------- //
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* begin slideshow layout */

.slideShow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slidesContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.slideCard {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 40vw;
  width: 100%;
}

.fa-chevron-right,
.fa-chevron-left {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 0.15s linear, opacity 0.15s linear;
}

.fa-chevron-right {
  right: 2%;
}

.fa-chevron-left {
  left: 2%;
}

.fa-chevron-right:hover,
.fa-chevron-left:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: white !important;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.fa-chevron-right:focus,
.fa-chevron-left:focus {
  color: white !important;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.fa-chevron-right:active,
.fa-chevron-left:active {
  color: white !important;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.slideShow:hover .fa-chevron-right {
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}

.slideShow:hover .fa-chevron-left {
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}

.slideNumberDots {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 5%;
  gap: 1.5vw;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  background-color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slideDot {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1.5vw;
  height: 0.4vw;
  width: 3.5vw;
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  background: white;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: left bottom;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: none;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, background 0.3s ease-in-out, outline 0.3s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.slideDot:hover {
  background: #1c69d3;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 2px solid black !important;
  outline-offset: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, background 0.3s ease-in-out, outline 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.slideDot.is-active {
  background: #1c69d3;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  outline: 2px solid black !important;
  outline-offset: 0px !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.slideDot:focus {
  outline: 2px solid black !important;
  outline-offset: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.slideDot:active {
  background-color: #1c69d3;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: background-color, transform 0.3s linear;
  outline: 2px solid black !important;
  outline-offset: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}


/* end slideshow layout */


/* begin animations */

.sliderDotHorizontalAnim {
  animation: sliderDotHorizontalAnim 7000ms linear forwards;
}

.sliderDotHorizontalAnim:hover {
  background: #1c69d3;
}

@keyframes sliderDotHorizontalAnim {
  from {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white 50%, #1c69d3 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: right bottom;
  }
  to {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white 50%, #1c69d3 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: left bottom;
  }
}

.slideCard img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<body>
  <div class="slideShow">
    <div class="slidesContainer">
      <div class="slideCard" title="2Series">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MABHqGy.jpg" alt="BMW 2 Series" />
      </div>
      <div class="slideCard" title="3Series">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ggy6iNU.jpg" alt="BMW 3 Series" />
      </div>
      <div class="slideCard" title="X3">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ucYCFcu.jpg" alt="BMW X3" />
      </div>
      <div class="slideCard" title="iX">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bQhvuOY.jpg" alt="BMW 5 Series" />
      </div>
      <div class="slideCard" title="5Series">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sLYH9Gy.jpg" alt="BMW 5 Series" />
      </div>
      <div class="slideCard" title="BMW Certified Pre-Owned">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kuOWIEJ.jpg" alt="BMW Certified Pre-Owned" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you try storing the lastly active item in a temporary variable and then assign its next item as active?

Comment: @Nikkkshit I can try. I'm not sure how that would work with the ability to move the slideshow manually with the buttons (going from 5 to 2 or 1 to 4, etc.) but I'll play around with it. Thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: Actually, I misunderstood your question sorry about it, but you can still try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple using an id, I was just targeting the slideshow and not the select dots that are created *after* the JS runs.

I added an id `id: 'slideNumberDotsContainer',` to the slide nav that the JS generates, then targeted that container after it was created to find the `is-active` class on whatever the current slide was and add and remove the animation inside of two functions, then just appended those functions to the pointer-events I already had set up.

```js
// ----- slideshow declarations ----- //
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
// -------------------- //


// ----- mod function ----- //
const mod = (n, m) => (n % m + m) % m;
// -------------------- //


// ----- build slider ----- //
const slideShow = (elSlideShow) => {

  const slideAnim = 500;
  const pause = 7000;

  const elSlider = el('.slidesContainer', elSlideShow);
  const elsSlides = els('.slideCard', elSlider);
  const elsDots = [];

  let autoPlayInterval;
  let index = elsSlides.length;
  let currentSlide = 0;

  if (index < 2) return;
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- transition ----- // 
  const trans = (ms = slideAnim) => {
    const cMod = mod(currentSlide, index);

    elSlider.style.transitionDuration = `${ms}ms`;
    elSlider.style.transitionTimingFunction = "ease-in-out";
    elSlider.style.transform = `translateX(${(-currentSlide - 1) * 100}%)`;

    elsSlides.forEach((elSlide, i) => elSlide.classList.toggle('is-active', cMod === i));
    elsDots.forEach((elDot, i) => elDot.classList.toggle('is-active', cMod === i));
    elsDots.forEach((elDot, i) => elDot.classList.toggle('sliderDotHorizontalAnim', cMod === i));
  };
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- nav buttons ----- //
  const moveLeft = () => {
    if (currentSlide <= -1) return;
    currentSlide -= 1;
    trans();
  };

  const moveRight = () => {
    if (currentSlide >= index) return;
    currentSlide += 1;
    trans();
  };

  const goTo = (index) => {
    currentSlide = index;
    trans();
  };
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- create controls ----- // 
  const elPrev = elNew('a', {
    type: 'a',
    className: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
    onclick: () => moveLeft(),
  });

  const elNext = elNew('a', {
    type: 'a',
    className: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
    onclick: () => moveRight(),
  });

  const elNav = elNew('div', {
    className: 'slideNumberDots',
    id: 'slideNumberDotsContainer',
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    const elDot = elNew('a', {
      type: 'a',
      className: 'slideDot',
      onclick: () => goTo(i)
    });
    elsDots.push(elDot);
  }
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- slide autoplay ----- //
  const dotPlaying = () => {
    var dotsContainer = document.getElementById('slideNumberDotsContainer');
    dotsContainer.querySelector('.is-active').classList.toggle('sliderDotHorizontalAnim', true);
    console.log('animated');
  };

  const dotStopped = () => {
    var dotsContainer = document.getElementById('slideNumberDotsContainer');
    dotsContainer.querySelector('.is-active').classList.toggle('sliderDotHorizontalAnim', false);
    console.log('not animated');
  };

  const autoplay = () => {
    autoPlayInterval = setInterval(moveRight, pause + slideAnim);
    dotPlaying();
  };

  const stop = () => {
    clearInterval(autoPlayInterval);
    dotStopped(autoPlayInterval);
  };
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- handle clones ----- // 
  elSlider.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    if (currentSlide <= -1) currentSlide = index - 1;
    if (currentSlide >= index) currentSlide = 0;
    trans(0);
  });
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- handle clones ----- // 
  elSlider.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    if (currentSlide <= -1) currentSlide = index - 1;
    if (currentSlide >= index) currentSlide = 0;
    trans(0);
  });
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- handle pointer events ----- // 
  elSlideShow.addEventListener('pointerenter', () => stop());
  elSlideShow.addEventListener('pointerleave', () => autoplay());
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- insert controls ----- // 
  elNav.append(...elsDots);
  elSlideShow.append(elNav, elPrev, elNext);
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- slide clones ----- // 
  elSlider.prepend(elsSlides[index - 1].cloneNode(true));
  elSlider.append(elsSlides[0].cloneNode(true));
  // -------------------- //


  // ----- functions on load ----- // 
  trans();
  autoplay();
  // -------------------- //
};


// ----- initiate slideshow ----- // 
els('.slideShow').forEach(slideShow);
// -------------------- //
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* begin slideshow layout */

.slideShow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slidesContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.slideCard {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 40vw;
  width: 100%;
}

.fa-chevron-right,
.fa-chevron-left {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 0.15s linear, opacity 0.15s linear;
}

.fa-chevron-right {
  right: 2%;
}

.fa-chevron-left {
  left: 2%;
}

.fa-chevron-right:hover,
.fa-chevron-left:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: white !important;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.fa-chevron-right:focus,
.fa-chevron-left:focus {
  color: white !important;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.fa-chevron-right:active,
.fa-chevron-left:active {
  color: white !important;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.slideShow:hover .fa-chevron-right {
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}

.slideShow:hover .fa-chevron-left {
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}

.slideNumberDots {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 5%;
  gap: 1.5vw;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  background-color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slideDot {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1.5vw;
  height: 0.4vw;
  width: 3.5vw;
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  background: white;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: left bottom;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: none;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, background 0.3s ease-in-out, outline 0.3s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.slideDot:hover {
  background: #1c69d3;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 2px solid black !important;
  outline-offset: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, background 0.3s ease-in-out, outline 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.slideDot.is-active {
  background: #1c69d3;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  outline: 2px solid black !important;
  outline-offset: 0px !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.slideDot:focus {
  outline: 2px solid black !important;
  outline-offset: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.slideDot:active {
  background-color: #1c69d3;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: background-color, transform 0.3s linear;
  outline: 2px solid black !important;
  outline-offset: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}


/* end slideshow layout */


/* begin animations */

.sliderDotHorizontalAnim {
  animation: sliderDotHorizontalAnim 7000ms linear forwards;
}

.sliderDotHorizontalAnim:hover {
  background: #1c69d3;
}

@keyframes sliderDotHorizontalAnim {
  from {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white 50%, #1c69d3 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: right bottom;
  }
  to {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white 50%, #1c69d3 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: left bottom;
  }
}

.slideCard img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<body>
  <div class="slideShow">
    <div class="slidesContainer">
      <div class="slideCard" title="2Series">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MABHqGy.jpg" alt="BMW 2 Series" />
      </div>
      <div class="slideCard" title="3Series">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ggy6iNU.jpg" alt="BMW 3 Series" />
      </div>
      <div class="slideCard" title="X3">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ucYCFcu.jpg" alt="BMW X3" />
      </div>
      <div class="slideCard" title="iX">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bQhvuOY.jpg" alt="BMW 5 Series" />
      </div>
      <div class="slideCard" title="5Series">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sLYH9Gy.jpg" alt="BMW 5 Series" />
      </div>
      <div class="slideCard" title="BMW Certified Pre-Owned">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kuOWIEJ.jpg" alt="BMW Certified Pre-Owned" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```